# jquery $.done is executed immedietely

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, promise

```
$.when(fetchingOutcomeTab()).done(alert("1"));

function fetchingOutcomeTab() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
        dfd.resolve('qqqqq');
    }, 2000);
    return dfd.promise();
}
```

I am trying to make alert("1") triggered waiting until fetchingOutcomeTab function done, but everytime it will triggered immedietely, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function to `.done()`. You're calling `alert()` immediately and passing its return value.

```
$.when(fetchingOutcomeTab()).done(() => alert("1"));
```

Comment: it works!! Thank you for your reply, and btw, can i call a function in resolve, and waiting this function finish, then go do the .done() function?

Comment: That's exactly what `resolve()` does -- it goes to the `.done()` callback.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your function returns a deferred object, you can chain `done()` directly to the function call. Also, [`done()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) expects a parameter that's a "function or array of functions".

```js
fetchingOutcomeTab().done(function() {
  console.log('resolved.');
});

function fetchingOutcomeTab() {

  console.log('Deferring...');

  var dfd = $.Deferred();

  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve('qqqqq');
  }, 2000);

  return dfd;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```